# Highstock default tooltip format symbol

Tags: jquery, tooltip, highcharts

I know we can use tooltip formatter to customize it. But what is the default tooltip format? I just want to use the default and append new data to it. I couldnt quite reproduce the default option, esp the colored bullet symbol per the series color.

```
    formatter: function() {
        var s = '<b>'+ Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.x)+'</b><br/>';
        s += '<span style="color:'+this.series.color+'">&#8226;'+this.series.name+'</span>:<b>'+this.point.y+' ';
        return s;
    }
```

Here the bullet is just showing as character

Answer (score 2):

Try to set [useHTML](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.useHTML) as true

```
tooltip:{ useHTML:true }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should note that the bullet you specified is not the one used by highcharts. They use the unicode char:

```
\u25CF
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ozh7owb4/1/

Comment: so how to remove bullet provideed by highcharts